# setOnSeekBarChangeListener with rxBinding

Tags: android, kotlin, seekbar, rx-binding

How can I use rxBinding to call `setOnSeekBarChangeListener`?

**My code :**

```
    view?.seekBarDisplay?.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object :
                SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
                override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar, 
    progress: Int, fromuser: Boolean) {

                   val backLightValue = (progress / 100f)
                   val layoutParams = activity?.window?.attributes
                   layoutParams?.screenBrightness = backLightValue
                   activity?.window?.attributes = layoutParams
                }

               override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {}

               override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {}
           })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As RxBinding 4.0 released, you have 4 options to implement the Seekbar using it:

1. the `SeekBar.changeEvents()`: with subscribing to this observable, you'll get notified when `onProgressChanged`, `onStartTrackingTouch`, and `onStopTrackingTouch` methods get called.
2. `SeekBar.changes()`: Notifies you only when any changes happen to the seekbar.
3. `SeekBar.userChanges()`: Notifies you only when any changes happen to the seekbar by User itself.
4. `SeekBar.systemChanges()`: Notifies you only when any changes happen to the seekbar by the system.

you can subscribe to these function as other usual Observables.

Here is a sample of the first method:

```
yourSeekBar.changes()
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe { seekBarChangeEvent ->
            when (seekBarChangeEvent) {
                is SeekBarProgressChangeEvent -> {}
                is SeekBarStartChangeEvent -> {}
                is SeekBarStopChangeEvent -> {}
            }
        }
```